# iPhone application crash when removing persistent store

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, restkit

I am having an issue deleting/resetting the core data database in my iphone app, typically when I call the following:

```
[self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:persistentStore error:&localError];
```

or

```
[self.managedObjectStore resetPersistentStores:] // Restkit
```

I am able to call this the first time the application launches but it seems whenever I have data loaded into the tableview, the application will hang when trying to remove the persistent store.  Is this the proper way to reset the core data database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starter, you need to `reset` all the `NSManagedObjectContext`s, because otherwise the contexts may have orphaned objects that will cause error.

Then, I always remove the sqlite file directly from file system and set `managedObjectContext` and `persistentStoreCoordinator` to nil (so that it will reconstruct the context and store from scratch on next access) rather than calling `removePersistentStore...`. But for this part, I am not sure which way is more appropriate.